# PanedWindow and global variables

Tags: python, tkinter

("General Kenobi")

Working with the tkinter module of python, I'm trying to recreate a quite complex graphical interface from something existing in VB. Everything was okay until I decided to make things a little more nice and clean with an initialization function including global variables. Since, every single PanedWindow won't show.

This is my initialization function :

```
def init():
    Tk().withdraw()

    global DL_COM1_NAME
    DL_COM1_NAME = StringVar()
```

And the main function with the graphical stuff :

```
def frame_Menu(init):

    init()

    # graphical user interface (GUI)
    # main frame
    main_frame = Tk()

    ...

    DL_COM_Panel1 = PanedWindow(orient='horizontal')
    DL_COM1 = Label(DL_COM_Panel1,bg='light slate blue',fg='white',font=('Arial','10','bold'),text='first :',anchor='w',relief='sunken',width=8)
    DL_COM_Panel1.add(DL_COM1)
    DL_COM1_Choice = Entry(DL_COM_Panel1,textvariable=DL_COM1_NAME,width=90)
    DL_COM_Panel1.add(DL_COM1_Choice)
    DL_COM1_Select = Button(DL_COM_Panel1,text='Browse',command=set_COM1filename)
    DL_COM_Panel1.add(DL_COM1_Select)
    DL_COM_Panel1.grid(row=7,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky='we',padx=(15,15),pady=(2.5,2.5))

    ...

    main_frame.mainloop()
```

The *set_COM1filename* function I'm using in "command" asks for a file by askopenfilename.

The PanedWindow I defined here won't open, and it's the same for every other ones, while everything was working with local variables. Furthermore, when I use the command prompt to run this, the process doesn’t stop when I click the quit button of my interface. Do you have any idea of the reason ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why are you creating two different Tks?

Comment: The problem would come from the fact that I'm defining my StringVar() for another Tk than the one I'm using for the main interface ?

Comment: You cannot use more than one `Tk` instance at a time.

Comment: So I should only define one on init and not another one on frame_Menu ?

Comment: @Hécatte Yes, only one Tk. tkinter saves one to use for default, but having multiple messes with that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test that at work tomorrow !

Comment: It's working, thanks again !